# .NET Screensaver Doesn't work with .DEFAULT User

Tags: .net, screensaver, system.net, defaultproxy

I've created a custom screensaver that works fine when users are logged in and have no activity for x amount of time. I would like this screensaver to be utilized when no one is logged in as well such as instances when there is a reboot. I applied screensaver registry settings to `HKEY_USER\.DEFAULT` and now have screensaver attempting to launch but I get the error message below. This screensaver load URLs and displays them which I suspect is causing the issue but the odd part is that this works fine for sessions where users are logged in. I've searched this issue out and tried different varieties of `<system.net> 
 <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" /> 
 </system.net>` settings to no avail.  There is something about the `.DEFAULT` user that is not allowing screensaver to work like it does for actual users. Any help towards a solution will earn you a cold beverage next time I'm in your town.  :)

Error Below
Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168880/error-creating-the-web-proxy-specified-in-the-system-net-defaultproxy-configur)

Comment: Tried all suggestions in that thread but I believe this issue is unique as it applies to .DEFAULT user as opposed to a logged in user.  In other words, when you first start PC up and no one has logged in I have a screensaver that loads but gets that error.  Only get the error in that state.

Comment: Would still appreciate any guidance if anyone has knowledge on how ".DEFAULT" user works in Windows 10.

Comment: Thought I'd add a little more commentary, this screensaver is used for an operations center where dashboards are loaded through a .NET app executing Selenium scripts.  It works great if you login one time and let it run and as a screensaver it makes it secure as well.  However, if PC is rebooted for any reason then the .DEFAULT user is used for screensaver until someone manually logs in with a username password.  Objective is to ensure screensaver is always running and if PC reboots then it kicks off again when PC comes back up.