# WebClient.DownloadString exceptions

Tags: c#

Here is the code I am using:

```
string url = @"https://www.google.co.uk/";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string info = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

When run, the exceptions

```
"ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 
'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section."
```

and

```
"SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied"
```

occur.

While I feel like the second exception could just be me doing something wrong, I am confused about the first. I have looked at other questions on StackOverflow which seem to talk about the app.config file. I have tried adding

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
</defaultProxy>
```

to this file but I wasn't sure where to put it or even if it would fix the problem (which it didn't). The program is stored on a network drive (which others have deemed relevant), I could put it onto an external drive but I don't have access to the C drive (a solution I have seen elsewhere).

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168880/error-creating-the-web-proxy-specified-in-the-system-net-defaultproxy-configur) question in particular but cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168880/error-creating-the-web-proxy-specified-in-the-system-net-defaultproxy-configur)

Comment: I have tried the solutions as detailed in my question which were the answers to that question. I cannot move to the C drive and adding to 'app.config' didn't work.