# C# - Rest Client WebProxy Configuration error

Tags: c#, rest-client

Trying to develop a RestClient in C#.

Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "Get";
request.ContentTpe = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";

request.Headers.Add("userid", "test\\owner");
request.Headers.Add("api-key", "2134feh");
request.Headers.Add("correlationid", "12343345");
request.Headers.Add("source-system", "ABC");
request.Headers.Add("useridtype", "Id");
request.Headers.Add("event-timestamp", "2016-09-05T13:15:30Z");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic WETREGFEWGFDW4353FEFDg34gdfd=");

try {
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    while (ex != null) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

App.config:

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Getting the below error for the above code and configuration.

Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the "system.net/defaultProxy" configuration section.

While trying the same using Postman client with proxy set as "default system proxy" and by setting off SSL certificate verification I am able to get the response.

What could be the reason for this?

Any inputs on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168880/error-creating-the-web-proxy-specified-in-the-system-net-defaultproxy-configur