# WebClient throw 'An exception occurred during WebClient request'

Tags: c#

I know that question has been ask a lot in the internet, but yet i didn't found a satisfying answer.

```cs
private string LocalSqlDriverDownloader()
        {
            ProgBar prograssBar = new();
            string sqlLocalDBUrl = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SqlLocalDB.msi";
            string fileName = "SqlLocalDB.msi";
            string directory = $@"{Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)}Download"; // C:\Download
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }
            using WebClient webClient = new();
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher?.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    (prograssBar.DataContext as PrograssbarWindowViewModel).PrograssBarValue = e.ProgressPercentage;
                });
            };
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                prograssBar.Close();
            };
            string downloadPath = $@"{directory}\{fileName}";
            try
            {
                webClient.DownloadFile(sqlLocalDBUrl, downloadPath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
            prograssBar.ShowDialog();
            return directory;
        }
```

I don't have a clue why this throw to me an exception, I tried to download other files, http and https, it doesn't seams to have any difference to the outcome.

The given exception:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An exception occurred during WebClient request.
  Source=PulserTesterMultipleHeads
  StackTrace:
   at PulserTesterMultipleHeads.Models.MainTestPageMV.LocalSqlDriverDownloader() in C:\Project\Models\MainTestPageMV.cs:line 955
   at PulserTesterMultipleHeads.Models.MainTestPageMV.LocalSQLDriverInstaller() in C:\Project\Models\MainTestPageMV.cs:line 905
   at PulserTesterMultipleHeads.Models.MainTestPageMV..ctor(Action closeAction, String catalogDesc) in C:\Project\Models\MainTestPageMV.cs:line 70
   at PulserTesterMultipleHeads.UserControls.MainTestPage..ctor() in C:\Project\UserControls\MainTestPage.xaml.cs:line 31
```

Comment: _"We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."_ - [WebClient Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: Please add the exception message and stacktrace to any question concerning exceptions.

Comment: @Fildor Exception message and stacktrace were added, thank you.

Comment: Could you highlight line 955?

Comment: Are there any inner exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Remove this whole construct:

```
try
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(sqlLocalDBUrl, downloadPath);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

and replace it by

```
webClient.DownloadFile(sqlLocalDBUrl, downloadPath);
```

Then you will still get an error, but at least you will be able to see what is wrong and where. The exception and maybe the inner exception will tell you in no uncertain terms what is wrong. The stack trace will tell you where it went wrong.

As it is, you have added this block and all it does is it *removes* the information you need to find out what is wrong. We cannot tell you what went wrong specifically, because your code intentionally removes it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I wasn't at work. I get the two following errors: 
1. ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating proxy for Web specified in configuration system 'system.net/defaultProxy'. 
For this, i think this is the answer to my problem [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6268221/13295451]
2. SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied The first one as I understant from the internet, is due to my organization restrictions, but I couldn't understant what invalid argument I'm sending.